# Get profile picture url from Facebook sdk

Tags: json, swift, facebook-graph-api, xcode7

I can't find a solution to get the url for a facebook profile picture.

When I login via Facebook I use this method to get profile information with Facebook graph api:

```
func getFBUserData() {
    // Create request for user's Facebook data
    let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"me", parameters:["fields": "id, name, first_name, middle_name, last_name, email, picture.type(large)"])

    // Send request to Facebook
    request.startWithCompletionHandler {

        (connection, result, error) in

        if error != nil {
            // Some error checking here
        }
        else {

            print(result)


            if let userData = result as? [String:AnyObject] {

                // Access user data
                let username = userData["first_name"] as! String


            }

        }

    }
}
```

I can easily parse first_name, email ect, but when it comes to picture url I don't know how to fecth that data. 
Here is my respons from Facebooks api:

```
{
    email = "dailocle@hotmail.com";
    "first_name" = Loc;
    id = 123456765432457654;
    "last_name" = Le;
    "middle_name" = Dai;
    name = "Loc Dai Le";
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xat1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/12246670_10207807554127440_7406917875415466413_n.jpg?oh=d394b200091f8973645300054e6b32b8&oe=572E6626";
        };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **imageURLForPictureMode:size** convenience method of the FBSDKProfile class.

```
let pictureURL = FBSDKProfile().imageURLForPictureMode(.Normal, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

```
self.dict = result as NSDictionary               
        println(self.dict)
        NSLog(self.dict.objectForKey("picture")?.objectForKey("data")?.objectForKey("url") as String)
```

Please try this

Comment: Thank for your answer @KamleshShingarakhiya, but it does not work

Comment: "Value of optional type 'AnyObject?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' og '?'?" - error at the first line var imageString...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do:

```
func getProfilePicture(account: ACAccount, handleSuccess: UIImage -> (), finally: () -> ()) {
    let r = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook, requestMethod: .GET, URL: NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me/picture")!, parameters: nil)
    r.account = account
    r.performRequestWithHandler({(data, urlresponse, error) in
        if error !== nil {
            //return
        } else if urlresponse.statusCode == 200 {
            handleSuccess(UIImage(data: data)!)
        } else {
            print("Unexpected status code \(urlresponse.statusCode)")
        }
        finally()
    })
}
```

If you really want to you can fetch the picture on the original request as you've done, but it's a lot of data so that's not how I'd approach it. I guess in your case that would mean `UIImage(data: userData["picture"])` although you may need to cast it to NSData.